# AGILE development framework recomendation

Tags: agile, crud, rad

I am new to AGILE development but i have a strong background in java and php. I need to do a CRUD application (university application and registration web app) as fast as possible and want recommendations on the best, fastest and easiest to learn AGILE dev framework for my work with preferably MySQL for data store.

Comment: thanx for the responses, What i meant to say was the fastest and easiest to learn FRAMEWORK which supports agile development.

Comment: Agile is not an acronym.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Agile dev framework"? What do you mean by framework? Is it some software, or you're referring to Scrum?

Answer (score 4):

Agile has nothing to do with which technologies you use to implement your application.  It's about the methodology you use to build your app.  The two are orthogonal.

I'd recommend Spring if you want a good framework for developing a web app in Java.  But Spring won't care if you use agile, waterfall, or anything other methodology.

Comment: thanx for the response, What i meant to say was the fastest and easiest to learn FRAMEWORK which supports agile development.

Comment: @deVIAntCoDE What is FRAMEWORK?

Comment: Read my response again - I recommend Spring.  I don't know if it'll be fastest or easiest for you, but I think it's the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by agile development framework?

By [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development):
"Agile software development is a group of software development methodologies based on iterative and incremental development, where requirements and solutions evolve through collaboration between self-organizing, cross-functional teams"

So agile is a way how you manage your project, not a framework in which you work (you can develop in agile way in any language).

Of course by agile you can understand sets of software development practices as:

- [Unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)
- [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)
- [Solid principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)

which you can easier implemented using additional frameworks/tools

Comment: hanx for the responses, What i meant to say was the fastest and easiest to learn FRAMEWORK which supports agile development.

Comment: I don't know any good frameworks in java or php (I'm developing mostly in .net), so I can't help you with choosing. But probably you should choose framework/language in which you feel comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if methodology choices are necessarily "orthogonal" to technology choices (as stated above). For example, most contemporary implementations of Agile strongly recommend practices such as TDD, unit testing, continuous integration, QA automation and the like. These practices are easier to adhere to if you make the right technology choices. The technology stack I've had most success with is as follows: Spring, Hibernate, Maven, Eclipse, Hudson, Log4J, JBoss, JUnit, soapUI. However, the above list is merely a guideline and is not comprehensive. One could, for example, easily swap Hudson for CruiseControl and perhaps be equally successful.